# How to convert one pdf to multiple png images with multithreading

Tags: java, multithreading, pdfbox

I used the following method to convert a pdf into multiple png images：

```
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.rendering.ImageType;
import org.apache.pdfbox.rendering.PDFRenderer;
import org.imgscalr.Scalr;

public class ImgUtil {
    public static List<String> convertPDFPagesToImages(String sourceFilePath, String desFilePath){
        List<String> urlList = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            File sourceFile = new File(sourceFilePath);
            File destinationFile = new File(desFilePath);
            if (!destinationFile.exists()) {
                destinationFile.mkdir();
                log.info("Folder Created ->:{} ", destinationFile.getAbsolutePath());
            }
            if (sourceFile.exists()) {
                log.info("Images copied to Folder Location: ", destinationFile.getAbsolutePath());
                PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(sourceFile);
                PDFRenderer pdfRenderer = new PDFRenderer(document);

                int numberOfPages = document.getNumberOfPages();
                log.info("Total files to be converting ->{} ", numberOfPages);

                String fileName = sourceFile.getName().replace(".pdf", "");
                String fileExtension = "png";
                /*
                 * 600 dpi give good image clarity but size of each image is 2x times of 300 dpi.
                 * Ex:  1. For 300dpi 04-Request-Headers_2.png expected size is 797 KB
                 *      2. For 600dpi 04-Request-Headers_2.png expected size is 2.42 MB
                 */
                int dpi = 300;// use less dpi for to save more space in harddisk. For professional usage you can use more than 300dpi

                for (int i = 0; i < numberOfPages; ++i) {
                    File outPutFile = new File(desFilePath + fileName +"_"+ (i+1) +"."+ fileExtension);
                    BufferedImage bImage = pdfRenderer.renderImageWithDPI(i, dpi, ImageType.RGB);
                    ImageIO.write(bImage, fileExtension, outPutFile);
                    urlList.add(outPutFile.getPath().replaceAll("\\\\", "/"));
                }

                document.close();
                log.info("Converted Images are saved at ->{} ", destinationFile.getAbsolutePath());
            } else {
                log.error(sourceFile.getName() +" File not exists");
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return urlList;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
     
         convertPDFPagesToImages("D:\\tmp\\report\\pdfPath\\61199020100754118.pdf", "D:\\tmp\\report\\pdfPath\\");
         
    }
}
```

But I found that when the number of pdf pages is relatively large, the image conversion is slower. I consider using multithreading to parse the images. Is it possible to convert a pdf into a picture through multiple threads or is there a similar method?

Comment: Which PDDocument class do you use? Implementation please.

Comment: You need to open the document several times, once for each thread because multithreading doesn't always work properly.

Comment: I use this class org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument

Comment: You do not need to run `ImageIO.write` part in same thread when iterating the `pdfRenderer.renderImageWithDPI` so even if renderImageWithDPI is not threadsafe you should be able to cut down some execution time using 2 threads - one read image and one write image. Note also that on some hardware ImageIO.write may be be faster if writing to memory buffer first before to filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to speed up this conversion would be to split image writing to a background thread. Set up an executorService before opening the PDF:

```
ExecutorService exec = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
List<Future<?>> pending = new ArrayList<>();
```

Instead of writing the image in same calling thread, just submit a new task to the service:

```
// ImageIO.write(bImage, fileExtension, outPutFile);
pending.add(exec.submit(() -> write(bImage, fileExtension, outImage.toFile())));
```

And function to perform the task:

```
private static void write(BufferedImage image, String fileExtension, File file) {
    try {
        ImageIO.write(image, fileExtension, file);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
    }
}
```

After closing the PDF document make sure the executor is finished:

```
for (Future<?> fut : pending) {
   fut.get();
}
exec.shutdown();
exec.awaitTermination(365, TimeUnit.DAYS);
```

Using more than one thread for `ImageIO.write` may not benefit you as it is heavy IO operation but as I said in the comment, experiment with writing to a large `ByteArrayOutputStream` and then the file may also help on your specific hardware.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I will test it in your way！